# Javascript page-break

Tags: javascript, page-break, page-break-inside

I need help
I have a problem with making reports invoices with pre-printed paper. when an item of the invoice exceeds the capacity, automatically the rest of the items will be printed onto a second page.
I use a javascript programming language. No one can give a solution?

```
for (var x = 1; x <= lineCount; x++){
    var strItem = '';
    var strUnit ='';
    var strJumlah ='';
    var strHargaSatuan ='';
    var strHargaTotal ='';
    if(recIV.getLineItemValue('item','item', x)){
        strItem = recIV.getLineItemText('item','item', x);
    }
    if(recIV.getLineItemValue('item','units', x)){
        strUnit = recIV.getLineItemText('item','units', x);
    }
    if(recIV.getLineItemValue('item','quantity', x)){
        strJumlah = recIV.getLineItemValue('item','quantity', x);
    }
    if(recIV.getLineItemValue('item','rate', x)){
        strHargaSatuan = recIV.getLineItemValue('item','rate', x);
    }
    if(recIV.getLineItemValue('item','amount', x)){
        strHargaTotal = recIV.getLineItemValue('item','amount', x);
    }

    strName += '   <tr style=\"font-size:13px\" line-height=\"11px\">';
    strName += '      <td width=\"10%\" align=\"center\">'+ x +'</td>';
    strName += '      <td width=\"35%\">'+strItem+'</td>';
    strName += '      <td width=\"15%\">'+strUnit+'</td>';
    strName += '      <td width=\"10%\">'+strJumlah+'</td>';
    strName += '      <td width=\"20%\">Rp '+addCommas(strHargaSatuan)+'</td>';
    strName += '      <td width=\"20%\">Rp '+addCommas(strHargaTotal)+'</td>';
    strName += '   </tr>';
}
```

Comment: How are you converting the HTML to pages? CSS has some printing support.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) *"No one can give a solution?"* Solution to what? You haven't described a problem.

Comment: CSS: `page-break-after`.

Answer (score 0):

I have written a web app that does this for a friend's business. What I do is create the element, append it to the actual DOM, then measure the height in pixels using `parseInt(getComputedStyle(item_list[i]).height)`

As soon as the height exceeds the available space I remove the last item and start appending to the 2nd page.